# Finding sphinxbase

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am very new to ROS so please excuse me if this is a completely silly question.

I am trying to compile a package given to me by someone.  I have an initialized  ros_ws folder with the package in the src subdirectory.  I type "catkin_make" and get the following error:

```
 -- checking for module 'sphinxbase'
 --   package 'sphinxbase' not found CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283
(message):
   A required package was not found Call Stack (most recent call first):  
 /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)  
 sphinx_mcl/CMakeLists.txt:8 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Here's the first few lines of the CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sphinx_mcl)

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   roscpp )
pkg_check_modules(SPHINX REQUIRED sphinxbase)
pkg_check_modules(POCKETSPHINX REQUIRED pocketsphinx)
```

It finds pocketsphinx o.k. and I've installed (practically) every Ubuntu package I can think of with the name sphinx in it.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219493/finding-sphinxbase/) by [jdbrody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23117/jdbrody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Assad.  Finally figured out  that  I was missing libsphinxbase-dev.  New to Ubuntu too!

---

Originally posted by [jdbrody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23117/jdbrody/) with karma: 28 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried re-installing the package 'pocketsphinx'? If not try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-pocketsphinx
```

Where  is your ROS distribution ( groovy,hydro,indigo etc). I hope this helps.
This tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Sphinx) might prove helpful too because 'sphinx' also doesn't seem running perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) with karma: 62 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1